# How do I publish a blog post to facebook so that the likes and comments are merged?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, wordpress, facebook-comments

I have a wordpress blog. Is it possible to publish a link to facebook so that the published link on my facebook business page has the same like counter as the one on the blog?

Also, can the comments section be the same?  (i.e. if I post the link on facebook, when someone comments, it automatically updates the comments section of the blog post and vice versa?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, each set of likes and comments are independent. There is no way to perform a merge of this data currently.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Wordpress plugin provides essentially most of what you can do currently to link Wordpress to the Facebook API http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook

You can't link the like counter of your posts and pages to your Facebook page, why? They're all separate post and pages. It only makes sense.

What you can do? You can announce your post on Facebook (timeline or business page) and all can comment on it. You can add Facebook comments to your posts and pages. The commenter has the choice of that comment showing up in his Facebook timeline. People can "like" the post announcement, or the post itself if you have the Like button on it. They both act separately because for people to actually like your post, they have to visit the page. For analytics it makes sense because you want to know who is in your Facebook page and who actually clicks to visit your site. Both are not the same, and that's the point.

If you want to actually merge your site with Facebook, it will have to be in the form of a Facebook app. If that's the direction you want to take, I believe you can find some help here on the matter.

Comment: Most of the plugins have the same functionality of modifying the template directly. I guess it would be easier to remove afterwards except the plugins I tried wouldn't put the comments on the single post pages for some reason.  I just ended up doing it manually.  It makes sense the way that it currently works, I just think it would be easy enough to make it show up on both, if there was part of the api that allowed it.  I guess there isn't, so there I am.  Thanks for your feed back!